# Php enclosure as a variable?

Tags: php

A begginers question. I have this little code:

```
<?php

$content = 'hello there, hello!';

echo substr_count("$content","hello");

?>
```

How could i replace 'hello there, hello!' part with another php enclosure, like

```
<?php the_content(); ?>
```

for example. What is the correct way of doing this? Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean with "enclosure"? There is no such thing. Also, you don't need the quotes around `$content`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php

echo substr_count(the_content(),"hello");

?>
```

This:

```
<?php
$a = 10;
?>

<?php
$b = 20;
?>

<?php
echo $a + $b;
?>

--output:--
30
```

is equivalent to:

```
<?php
$a = 10;

$b = 20;

echo $a + $b;
?>
```

Comment: Except for whitespace, of course; the former outputs two extra new lines.

Answer (score 0):

If `the_content` does not return a meaningful value but rather `echo`s things out, use [output buffering](http://www.php.net/outcontrol):

```
ob_start();
the_content();
$captured_content = ob_get_clean();
echo substr_count($captured_content, "hello");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$content = the_content();
echo substr_count($content,"hello");
```

or

```
echo substr_count(the_content(),"hello");
```

It is really the basics, try to look at some tutorials ;)